# Producing Race Condition

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition, critical-section

I am trying to produce a race condition (assuming that there exists a critical section in the `csfunc`) with the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
  
int cs = 0;

void* csfunc(void* arg){

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){

        cs++;
        cs--;

        if (cs!=0){
        
            printf("cs: %d\n", cs);
        }
    }
}
  
  
int main(){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t,NULL,csfunc,NULL);
        pthread_join(t,NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I assume that 100 threads with 1000000 iterations are enough to do a lot of race conditions. Nonetheless, my code is not producing even one single printing of the value of `cs`. Any ideas? Or am I missing something?

PS> Please note that I am using the `gcc` compiler with the following command

```
gcc cs.c -lpthread -o cs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do join, it waits until that thread is finished then continues the loop. So you should put thread handles in an array and wait for all of them.

```
pthread_t handles[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    pthread_create(&handles[i],NULL,csfunc,NULL);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    pthread_join(handes[i],NULL);
```

Comment: Would you please explain more. I was expecting such an answer but can't know why. Isn't the thread supposed to start independent from the loop? Thank you

Comment: There really nothing else to say. `create` creates a thread, and `join` waits for it to finish like bca said. You created thread, waited for it to end, created thread, waited for it to end, created thread, waited for it to end, etc. You never had more than one thread running at a time! It's like you didn't have any threads at all.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, I think my mistake was as follows: I though that pthread_create like declares the thread and pthread_join run it, but it is rather that join refers to wait until finished: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html. I have been few years far away from C++. Thank you

Comment: Threads start running immediately. There might be a way of telling them to start suspended? But it's not the default. And if there's not, you could also use a mutex or the like to freeze them once they start.

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNEHME, Re, "I have been few years far away from C++." Your program looks like "C", and the `gcc...` command you used to compile it looks like "C". Maybe you could compile the same program with a C++ compiler, but _don't!_ Don't call `pthread_...` functions from C++. If you want threads in a C++ program, then use `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, etc. instead.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, you are totally right, thx for pointing it out..